Connect Metabase to database of choice by default using docker compose
I have the following docker-compose.yml file
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

services:
  timescale:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg15
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: timescaledb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
    volumes:
      - ./timescaledb-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  metabase_admin_mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: metabase
      MYSQL_USER: metabase_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: metabase_password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-umetabase_user", "-pmetabase_password"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 30

  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3001:3000" # Changed port mapping to 3001:3000
    environment:
      MB_DB_TYPE: mysql
      MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
      MB_DB_PORT: 3306
      MB_DB_USER: metabase_user
      MB_DB_PASS: metabase_password
      MB_DB_HOST: metabase_admin_mysql
      MB_DB_TZ: UTC  # Setting timezone
      MB_DB_DBNAME_EXTRA: postgres
      MB_DB_SERVER_EXTRA: timescale
      MB_DB_PORT_EXTRA: 5432
      MB_DB_USERNAME_EXTRA: timescaledb
      MB_DB_PASSWORD_EXTRA: pass123
    depends_on:
      metabase_admin_mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

What i am attempting to do?
I am trying to spin up a metabase service which connects to mysql for admin related data and timescaledb for analytics purpose my default.
What happens right now?
When i run docker compose up the service spins up fine. I can see Metabase spin up fine and i can see that it is connected to mysql for admin related data. However i manually have to add the timescaledb and i am wondering if there is a way to have it connect to timescaledb by default?
I could not find any documents on Metabase page and looked around everywhere. I am wondering is this even possible?
I thought by adding the following block i would have success but i don't
      MB_DB_DBNAME_EXTRA: postgres
      MB_DB_SERVER_EXTRA: timescale
      MB_DB_PORT_EXTRA: 5432
      MB_DB_USERNAME_EXTRA: timescaledb
      MB_DB_PASSWORD_EXTRA: pass123

I could not find anything in metabase documentation so i am starting to think this is not possible but just wondering if it is and if so how would i do it?

from where did you get that _EXTRA parameters? I don't think it's possible to use 2 databases so maybe you would be fine just using timescale?

Yeah you’re right it’s not working . Now I’m looking to see if I can even use metabase api to add database via sh script after it has spun up

Seems like you need to add a dependency to the timescale container like the one you have to the mysql admin container. It's just a guess, but probably postgres is not ready when metabase tries to connect.
